ASP Classic - submit form when checkbox is clicked
Using ASP Classic, VBScript...  I have a side nav bar that displays a list of fly rod makers from the database as checkboxes.  I have a form that submits the page when a user checks a few Makers, then clicks on the Maker button.  This works great, but I'd like to upgrade it to remove the Maker button and submit the form each time a user checks a checkbox.
            <% for i = LBound(subIDArray) to UBound(subIDArray)%>
                <br>
                "  /><%=subCATArray(i)%>
            <%next %>

Here is my code:
    <div class="sidenav">
        <form method = "post" >
            <input type = "submit" value = "Makers" style="height:50px; width:75px font-size:.7rem;" />
            <input type = "submit" value = "Select All" style="height:50px; width:75px font-size:.87rem;" />
                <% for i = LBound(subIDArray) to UBound(subIDArray)%>
                    <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="maker" value="<%=subIDArray(i)%>"  /><%=subCATArray(i)%>
                <%next %>
       
                <%
                    menuarray = ""
                    menuarray = Request.Form("maker") ' Name of the Control
                %>
            
                <br> 
        </form>
    </div>

I have tried adding some javascript and jquery code that others on this site suggest, but nothing seems to work.
